# Ember JSONAPI Adapter with Django REST framwork json API

Tags: django, api, ember.js, adapter, json-api

I am using [EmberJS](https://emberjs.com) with [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). For my API do I want to use JSONAPI. For this I installed [Django rest framework json api](https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io). And in Ember do I use the [JSONAPIAdapter](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter).

When my Ember app tries to get **/appointments/** everything is fine and

```
"type": "Appointment"
```

but when my Ember Store tries to save an appointment it goes to the correct URL but

```
"type": "appointments"
```

after some testing I concluded that the only type that works is "Appointment", not "appointment" and neither "appointments" or "Appointments".

I don't know why the Ember JSONAPIAdapter does this, but is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Please accept the answer, which helped you best. SO questions should have an accepted answer. Thx

Answer (score 2):

The JSON API spec itself doesn't care if type is singular, plural, dasherized, underscored, etc... It is agnostic about inflection rules.

But Ember uses a convention by default (the examples at [JSON API spec](https://jsonapi.org/) use the same convention). Ember's JSONAPIAdapter will pluralize and dasherize your types by default.

The important thing, is that your client and your server use **the same convention**. I think that's your problem.

If your server uses another convention you could customize your JSONAPIAdapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { underscore } from '@ember/string';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  pathForType(type) {
    return underscore(type);
  }
});
```